# use variable expansion failing in sed for inserting string with 4 tabs in a file

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Team,

I need to insert a string at a certain line in a file after certain tabs.

bonus: I also need to skip insertion if it already exists.

## cat test.txt

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

```
sed -i '3i\ \t\t\t\t<file branch-rate="0.0">' test.txt
```

## cat test.txt < after above insertion.

```
1
2
                                <file branch-rate="0.0">
3
4
5
```

using variable assignment

```
ln=5
```

```
sed -i '${ln}i\ \t\t\t\t<file branch-rate="0.0">' test.txt
sed: -e expression #1, char 4: extra characters after command
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use double quotes `"` so your variables can expand. It is also a good idea to create a backup file while using in-place editing.

You can try this `sed`

```
$ sed -i.bak "${ln}i\ \t\t\t\t<file branch-rate=\"0.0\">" test.txt
```

Comment: bonus request1: is there a way i can say `4t\` ? and is there an equivalent on mac?

Comment: also how would i do with string expansion like `insert_me="<file branch-rate=\"0.0\">"` inside the sed? `sed -i.bak "${ln}i\ \t\t\t\t${insert_me}"`

Comment: @AhmFM You can achieve it the same way as above. The command you have above will work with the variable if the quotes are escaped. Regarding the first question, can you please elaborate as I do not understand?

Comment: Perhaps `sed -i.bak ${ln}'i\ \t\t\t\t<file branch-rate="0.0">' test.txt`

Comment: `4t\` implies inserting 4 tab spaces

Comment: I tried but it is inserting quotes `"` also in the text file.

Comment: @AhmFM What do you mean by `it is inserting quotes`? Is that not what you want? It seems to work as expected on my side. Please provide additional details or open a  new question with the current issue.